# How to get current execution of a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am doing a little maven plugin that must have multiple executions that can have equal phases and goals. In this plugin I need to get the current execution to get its configuration.

I can get all executions by `plugin.getExecutions()` but how to find out which execution is current in order to do `execution.getConfiguration()`?

Comment: As Robert already stated why do you need the information about execution in your plugin? Please elaborate more in detail what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't care about that. Just focus on the configuration by annotating fields with @Parameter as described at https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html and Maven will handle the rest for you.
Take a look at other plugins too to get a better understanding of maven plugins.

Comment: Really, Maven ensures that you will the right configuration at the right time. I'd suggest to read https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html or share your project.